# Converting factor value to new variable which stores count of how many times it occured in the factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I have ATP data set from kaggle. I am working on it in R.In the data set I have various variables like match date, city, tournament name, winner name, loser name, total set won by match winner, total set won by match loser, total games won by winner, total games won by loser and so on.

My attention is on match winner and match loser columns.
These columns are factor variables which have the value of player name.

Now what I want is to plot a graph of match win-loss ratio for different player(say top 5 or top 10 players having highest win-loss ratio) where the x-axis represents the name of player and y-axis represents the win-loss ratio of that player.

How do I create this specific graph. I have tried using pipe lining in dplyr package as follows:
Winner and Loser are factorial variables.

```
roger_wins <- atp %>% filter(Winner == "Federer R.") %>% count(Winner)
roger_loss <- atp %>% filter(Loser == "Federer R.") %>% count(Loser)
```

But using this way it has to be hard coded for each player. How to I do this using code for top 5 or top 10 players(according to win-loss)
Please provide the solution in R.
This is the page where the data set can be found:
https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016

Comment: Please paste a small sample of the data into your question using `dput()`, rather than sending people to another site to download the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you can do something like this:

1. Use the **table** function to colapse the data
2. Then you can use the **apply** function over the output of the first point

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured it out though. But I feel I did it in a more complex manner. You can see my analysis and how I managed to do what I wanted here :

Comment: The link is : https://www.kaggle.com/arathee2/d/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016/surface-wise-analysis